# How to convert person mm/dd/yyyy D.O.B into actual age. Selenium, Java

Tags: java, date-difference, date

I want to convert date of birth into age.
This is my code.

```html
String patientDOB = driver.findElement(id("patient_profile_widget_form_birthday")).getAttribute("value");
```

I'm getting date as: 03/01/1961

How could I convert this into age? 
I want output like => 57 Years

Any idea? :)

Comment: Ehm, get the current date and then do a subtraction on both dates probably?

Comment: convert this into age from `03/01/1961` to `57 Years` would be core language specific task. Why is `Selenium` tagged here? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AKSW 100% correct. yes something like that

Comment: (1) Parse your string into a `LocalDate` (2) Calculate years between that date and today. For each of the two subtasks your search engine will give you many hits.

Answer (score 1):

using java 8

```
public int calculateAge(
  LocalDate birthDate) {
    // validate inputs ...
    return Period.between(birthDate, LocalDate.now());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final DateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
String patientDOB = driver.findElement(id("patient_profile_widget_form_birthday")).getAttribute("value");

Date dateOfBirth = getDateFromString(patientDOB);
public Date getDateFromString(final String patientDOB) {
    try {
        return FORMATTER.parse(param);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new Exception("ParseException occurred while parsing date ", e);
    }
}

public static int getAge(Date dateOfBirth) {
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar birthDate = Calendar.getInstance();
birthDate.setTime(dateOfBirth);
if (birthDate.after(today)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("You don't exist yet");
}
int todayYear = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int birthDateYear = birthDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int todayDayOfYear = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int birthDateDayOfYear = birthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int todayMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int birthDateMonth = birthDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int todayDayOfMonth = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int birthDateDayOfMonth = birthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int age = todayYear - birthDateYear;

// If birth date is greater than todays date (after 2 days adjustment of leap year) then decrement age one year
if ((birthDateDayOfYear - todayDayOfYear > 3) || (birthDateMonth > todayMonth)){
    age--;

// If birth date and todays date are of same month and birth day of month is greater than todays day of month then decrement age
} else if ((birthDateMonth == todayMonth) && (birthDateDayOfMonth > todayDayOfMonth)){
    age--;
}
return age;
```

}

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Not the exact answer which I want :/

Answer (score -2):

Create a wrapper method that get you string as argument,

use:

```
 String[] parts = string.split("/");
```

and select the 3rd item of the list.

then you just have to use:

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

to get your year. Then you just convert your year string into an int and substract them

Comment: that's not correct and an ugly way...and not taking into account day and month is probably a bad idea, as those clearly matter when computing the age. Java has parsers for date string, Java provides subtraction for date objects, so ...

Comment: answer him yourself then ?

Comment: no, I'm dumb and have no good coding experience in Java

Comment: why would you downvote a working solution if you cant propose a better one